# Edit the wp-config of a Wordpress webpack build

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, webpack

I inherited the code from a previous developer that is a Wordpress setup using webpack and docker-compose to run it locally. There is a part where it is checking to see if a constant RECAPTCHA_V3_PUBLIC_KEY exists but it isn't set anywhere in the code and I am assuming it is pulling it from wp-config but I can't figure out how to edit the config. The whole codebase is just wp-content and a docker-compose.yml, should I add the constant in the .yml file? Am I just missing something completely? Here is the code that is looking for the key:

```
'recaptchaPublicKey' => ( defined('RECAPTCHA_V3_PUBLIC_KEY') ? constant('RECAPTCHA_V3_PUBLIC_KEY') : '' ),
```

This is in a 'theme-scripts.php' file which is loaded in 'functions.php'. I'm so confused by this setup

Comment: Do you **need** to change anything? What would happen if you just keep everything as it is?

Comment: @NicoHaase reCaptcha fails so I can't test the form submissions. It says the public key is blank so I'm trying to figure out where I need to set it so that it can capture it and use it where it's needed

Comment: And what happens if you just set the key in that given file? Based on a single line of code and a bunch of filenames, there is literally no way of helping you

Comment: @NicoHaase wait I was just being very dumb. I am going to expose the html folder for the site using docker so that I can have access to the wp-config then should have access to setting the configs there. I got too caught up in the webpack part of this that I didn't think about the docker half

Comment: Yep that worked... I'm dumb sorry, I appreciate the help though